# WPF Focus on same control when do navigation back

Tags: wpf

In WPF how to keep focus on the same control from where navigate to second page.

For example I am having two WPF Pages "FirstPage.xaml" and "SecondPage.xaml". In First page I am having two text box and two combobox. From FirstPage I write a code to redirect to second page when click on space button from second combobox. In second page I write a code "NavigationService.GoBack();" on button click.
When I return to FirstPage from SecondPage then thr focus is on First Text box controlonly and not on second combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
IInputElement focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
```

in the FirstPage. When you navigate back from the SecondPage just set focus to `focusedControl`

If you are navigating using *keyboard*, try

```
IInputElement focusedControl =  Keyboard.FocusedElement;
```

EDIT:

I would suggest you to keep a `static` global class. For eg:

```
static class Globals
{
   public static IInputElement MyFocusedControl = null; 
}
```

You can now access it using `Globals.MyFocusedControl`

So as in your case suppose *FirstPage.xaml* contains a `Button` named `btnNavigateToNextPage`, assign the value to global static variable in its *click* event like:

```
private void btnNavigateToNextPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   Globals.MyFocusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this); //this here is FirstPage
   /*
     Code here to call the second page
     '
     '
   */
}
```

And in the *SecondPage.xaml* you probably might have a `Button` to navigate back. Let's say it's name is `btnNavigateToPreviousPage`.

So in its *click* event you can write like this:

```
private void btnNavigateToPreviousPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   /*
     Code here to navigate back to the first page
     '
     '
   */

    //Add this in the last line
    Globals.MyFocusedControl.Focus(); //This will set focus to the previous control
}
```

Hope this might get you going, if not tinker around a bit, google also. It's not that difficult.

**EDIT**: Here is the code snippet that you added in the comment:

```
public Page1() 
{ 
   InitializeComponent(); 
   Globals.MyFocusedControl = txtCode; //Why are you assigning txtCode here
   Globals.MyFocusedControl.Focus();   //when what you want is txtName. Remove both of these lines
} 
private void txtName_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (e.Key == Constants.REDIRECTKEY) 
   { 
      Globals.MyFocusedControl = txtName; //Here you have assigned the control
      NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2()); 
   } 
}
```

In Page2:

```
 Button_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
 { 
    NavigationService.GoBack(); 
    Global.Control.Focus(); //But what is this???? Delete it
    Globals.MyFocusedControl.Focus(); //Use this instead.
 }
```

Comment: Can you please update In which event I need to set focus to focusedControl? Which event will fire when we back from navigated page?

Comment: Hello @KaruppusamyKK ! I've updated my answer, try it out. If it works for you, accept this as answer by clicking the tick on the left :)

Comment: Hi.. The above solution working fine when not focus on textbox control on Page Initialize. If we set focus on first text box on "public FirstPage()" then the above solution not working.  In the below code I set focus in txtCode control. So even if I navigate from second page the focus is on txtCode control only and not on the control from which I navigated to another page.                                          
     public FirstPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtCode.Focus();

        }

Comment: If you are setting focus manually like `txtCode.Focus();` it won't work. So write this after setting focus:  `Globals.MyFocusedControl =  txtCode;`. Kindly note whenever you apply focus from _code behind_ ie. if you are applying focus to a control _manually_, you would have to set it from code;. Hope u got the point :)

Comment: Hi, I did the same but not working.
Page 1:

 public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Global.Control = txtCode;
            Global.Control.Focus();
        }
         txtName_PreviewKeyDown()
        {
            if (e.Key == Constants.REDIRECTKEY)
            {
                Global.Control = txtName;
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2());
}
        }

Page 2:

       Button_Click()
        {
           
                NavigationService.GoBack();
                Global.Control.Focus();
            
        }

Comment: Using the above code still focus on txtCode only and not on txtName when redirecting.

Comment: //Why are you assigning txtCode here => In Page load I want to focus cursor in txtCode control.
//But what is this???? Delete it => Due to space issue I used "Control" instead of "MyFocusedControl".

So now I want to focus on "txtCode" when page load but during navigation I want to focus on controls from which I redirected to another page here "txtName"